# How to return a string from emscripten/webassembly function to a c caller

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

Trying to follow emscripten tutorial, passing parameters between C calls to emscripten, but only numbers are passed properly, not strings. How do I return a string back to C from js library call?

test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <emscripten.h>
extern char *getText(void);

int main() {
    printf(getText());
    return 0;
}
```

mylib.js:

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
    getText: function() {
        return "a test string";
    }
});
```

build command:

```
emcc test.c -o test.html --js-library mylib.js
```

The output I expect to see is  "a test string", but what I actually see is "emcc"

I have looked far and wide on stackoverflow ans elsewhere, but there is nothing I could find about returning string values from JS to C, only about passing them to JS from C, so this is not a duplicate of any other question I could find.

What gives?

Comment: In JavaScript, strings are managed internally and you can treat them like a first-class type.  In C, strings are arrays of `char` ending in a `\0`.  The associated memory must be allocated, and then freed.  Take a look at stringToUTF8 (https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/preamble.js.html) to copy a JS String into pre-allocated memory.

Comment: @Charles, the link explains how to return string as a parameter in a call, but not how to return string as a return value, as far as I can see. Does it mean that something like C: char *s = getJsString(); is not possible at all? And that instead I should use char **s; getJsString(&s); with the setValue in the JS implementation of getJsString()?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the answer OP is looking for, but have you considered wrapping the exposed functions within C++ to circumvent the issue? `const char*` would require some smart wrapping in order to work flawlessly with JS strings. If you wrap those functions in C++ and return `std::string` the pros might be bigger than cons.